# Android apk generation

Tags: android

Is it possible to generate .apk file from our application?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If there is no error in your application then sure it is possible to generate an apk. Have a look at the google docs on this and come back here if you encounter problems with generating an apk.

Comment: no i have one application in which the user have to select deifferent layouts then genrate a new .apk file and use in his application

Comment: That seems like an extremely roundabout way to implement user preferences...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to work offline? The reason I'm asking is because I wouldn't want to embed my own private Market key within my own application, I'd probably want to use a server-side application that does the signing at least. And then, if you do the signing on a server, you might as well do as much of the work on there as possible, that should be much easier to do that way.